# How to fit the image view in the screen based on android device?

Tags: android

I need to design the UI part in android device is,

[image]

Actually I'm having one title bar image and  four piece of menu image.

I'm using relative layout for designing this menu. But every time it's having some problem to show the last image in device.

How Can I design this?Please help me.

Comment: what u have tried till now ? it is simple.google it.

Comment: post you code that you have try to design this UI.

Answer (score 1):

Your should use below code for achieving it ..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnHeader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnMenu1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnHeader"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnMenu2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnMenu1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnMenu3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnMenu2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnMenu4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnMenu3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image2" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image3" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image4" 
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```